# OPcache not updating when file size change is small

Tags: php, invalidation, opcache

On my development VM OPcache doesn't invalidate a file's cache if the changes are small. The amount of time between changes seems not to be taken into account. I often have to add a bunch of bogus comments (~80 characters) to get OPcache to take notice. With OPcache disabled, the problem goes away.

I would really like to keep OPcache enabled on my dev VM since it speeds things up quite a bit and keeps me consistent with production. Is there anything I can do to make sure that OPcache invalidates a file after even few character changes?

PHP 5.5.14
Apache 2.4.9
Ubuntu 14.04

OPcache settings:

```
opcache.enable                  = true
opcache.enable_cli              = false
opcache.use_cwd                 = true
opcache.validate_timestamps     = true
opcache.inherited_hack          = true
opcache.dups_fix                = false
opcache.revalidate_path         = false
opcache.log_verbosity_level     = 1
opcache.memory_consumption      = 1024.00 = MB
opcache.interned_strings_buffer = 16
opcache.max_accelerated_files   = 4000
opcache.max_wasted_percentage   = 0.05
opcache.consistency_checks      = 0
opcache.force_restart_timeout   = 180
opcache.revalidate_freq         = 0
opcache.preferred_memory_model  
opcache.blacklist_filename  
opcache.max_file_size           = 0
opcache.error_log 
opcache.protect_memory          = false
opcache.save_comments           = true
opcache.load_comments           = true
opcache.fast_shutdown           = true
opcache.enable_file_override    = false
opcache.optimization_level      = 4294967295
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [the current documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/opcache.configuration.php#ini.opcache.validate-timestamps), `validate_timestamps` should be boolean. Have you tried it as `1`?

It might be worth checking all the other settings, too.